# function argument

Tags: c

What is the below highlighted code intended to do ? Why don't we not use the arguments at all ?

```
int fun( int a, int b)
{
    (void) a; // <<<
    (void) b; // <<<

    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's a way of preventing the compiler from warning about "unused parameters". It doesn't actually consume anything (the expression is discarded).

Comment: With GCC (and GCC-alikes), `__attribute__ ((unused))` is better but less portable. There's probably something similar for MSVC.

Comment: Some compilers also support `#pragma unused`, but again it's not portable.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore '`**`' is only for highlighting. Paul R edited to make it more obvious.

Comment: @nmichaels: Better in which way? "Less portable" seems to indicate "worse" so what is the advantage?

Comment: @undur: Better in that it doesn't try to trick the compiler into doing something pointless. Also better in that it's obvious what it's for, so you don't get people asking this question on SO.